# Why can't my module access a variable which it should have imported?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my simplified code:

`main.py:`

```
import vars, module

module.function()
```

`module.py`:

```
class Cage:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def function():
    print(mode)

from vars import *
```

`vars.py:`

```
from module import Cage

cage = Cage()
mode = True
```

When I run `main.py`, it gives the error code `NameError: name 'mode' is not defined`.

Why doesn't it give the expected value `True`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `vars.py` is making a circular import of `Cage` again before it can get to the line that initializes `mode`, resulting in `from vars import *` not being able to find `mode` as a name in the namespace of the partially-loaded `vars` module.

You can make `module.py` import `vars` as a module without importing its names first to let `vars.py` be fully loaded, and reference `vars.mode` in `function` instead so that by the time `function` is called, the name `mode` is available in the `vars` module:

```
def function():
    print(vars.mode)

import vars
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/FabulousOldAggregator

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I still don't quite understand what's the error. When `main.py` imports `module.py` it should run the code inside it which is `from vars import *`, which runs `vars.py`. At first it should import `Cage` from `module.py` but why does it stop there? Shouldn't it run the code after it too and define `mode`?

Comment: No, statements in Python code are run sequentially, one by one, so `mode = True` cannot be run until the statement `from module import Cage` finishes. The `import` statement is not a declaration, but an actual imperative to execute the code to be imported.

Comment: I understand, but why does the import stop when `from module import Cage` is called? Shouldn't it import `Cage` and then go on with defining `mode`?

Answer (score 0):

This works, 
In main....
    module.function(vars.mode)

In module.....
def function(mode):
    print(mode)

In vars....
no changes

Comment: As I said this is a simplified version of my code. I want to know why this doesn't work not how I can change this simple code to work.